# How do you run both the API-Manager and the WebApp together?

Tags: reactjs, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Currently I am trying to download and load up the API-M which works but trying to connect it to the WebApps it seems like there isn't any return. Nothing is changed in my files yet and I would like to modify the react files inside the WSO2 webapp but I can't figure out why it doesn't seem to want to run.

https://wso2.com/api-manager/

Comment: Are you trying to modify the UI?

Comment: Yes yes! RnR. I am trying to modify the UI. I already have ran the API-Manager.bat and started to run it on VsCode, but running it on node 16.19.1 still causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the UI, please follow the documentation on [1]. You will need node 16.x to build the latest versions of the UI (assuming that you use APIM 4.1.0 or 4.2.0. You can also follow this medium article[2] if you need to do development level changes to the UI.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/customizing-the-developer-portal/advanced-customization/#adding-advanced-ui-customizations-to-wso2-api-m-uis

[2] - https://tharanidk.medium.com/applying-ui-changes-in-wso2-api-manager-a6f1c1d70167